# How many of them are apples?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, percentages

> In a huge pile of apples & oranges, both ripe & unripe mixed together, $15 \text{%}$ are unripe fruits. Of the unripe fruits, $45 \text{%}$ are apples. Of the ripe ones, $66 \text{%}$ are oranges. If the pile contains a total of 5692000 fruits, how many of them are apples?

$a) \ 2029198   \ \ \ \ \ \ \  \  \ \ \ b) \ 2467482 \ \ \  \ \ \  \ \ \ \ \  c) \ 2789080  \ \ \ \ \ \  \ \  d) \ 3577422 $

my try:

number of unripe fruits $=\frac{15}{100}\cdot 5692000=853800$

number of apples $=\frac{45}{100}\cdot 853800=384210$

but the correct answer is a) $2029198$ but i don't know how to reach this answer. some please help me or give me some hint to solve it.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have only given the number of *unripe* apples.  Out of the remaining ripe fruit, which total $85$ percent of $5692000$, $100-66 = 34$ percent of those are apples.  You must add those into your total, and you will obtain $2029198$.

Comment: can i say $ripe fruits +unripe fruits=5692000$ ? or $apples +oranges=5692000$ ?

Comment: @Bhaskara-III: Both of those are true.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: There are also ripe apples. Any ripe fruit that is not an orange is a ripe apple.